# how to stop fetching data of shorten URL API because it's continuously adding same fetched link data with multiple different shortened versions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-hook-form

Using https://shrtco.de/docs/ for fetching my input data but it's continuously fetching it and adding to my displayLink array with different short url versions. I can add another link and it gets added to it but how do i stop it from duplicating or filter out a single originial link?

I get output like this [screenshot of logged output](https://gyazo.com/42e101b0e534d7be80ed7ff9daf2933b) & it keeps on adding to that displayLinks state with more same link but diff versions.

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from 'axios';
import Loading from '../../images/Ripple-1s-200px.svg'

const Shorten = () => {
    // get built in props of react hook form i.e. register,handleSubmit & errors / watch is for devs
    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors} } = useForm();

    //1. set user original values to pass as params to url
    const [link, setLink] = useState('');

    //2. set loader initial values to false 
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    //3. pass the fetched short link object into an array so we can map
    const [displayLinks, setDisplayLinks] = useState([]);

    //fetch the shortened url link using async method to show loading
    useEffect(() => {
        let unmounted = false;
        async function makeGetRequest() {
            try {
                let res = await axios.get('https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten', { params: { url: link } });
                //hid loader if u get response from api call
                    if (!unmounted && res.data.result.original_link !== displayLinks.original_link) {
                        setLoading(false);
                        //add the data to allLinks array to map
                        return setDisplayLinks(displayLinks => [...displayLinks, res.data.result]);
                    }

                } 
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error, "inital mount request with no data");
            }

        }
        //invoke the makeGetRequest here 
        makeGetRequest();
       
        return () => {
            unmounted = true;
        }

        //passing dependency to re render on change of state value
    }, [displayLinks, link]);

        // onSubmit form log data into a variable
        const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            //puttin data in a variable to pass as url parameter if valid
            setLink(data.userLink);
            //add loading here after data is set to state
            setLoading(!false);
        }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <label></label>
                <input
                    {...register("userLink", {required: "Please add a link"})}
                    type="url"
                    id="userLink"
                />
                {errors.userLink && <span>{errors.userLink.message}</span>}
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
            {
                loading ?
                    <div className="loader" id="loader">
                        <img src={Loading} alt="Loading" />
                    </div>
                        :   <div>
                                {
                                    displayLinks.map((el) => {
                                        return (
                                            <div key={el.code}>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h5>{el.original_link}</h5>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h5>{el.full_short_link}</h5>
                                                    <button>Copy</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Shorten;
```

Comment: useEffect gets called everytime the dependencies you have passed changes. So what is happening is you are calling the API and setting the result to displayLinks state variable. Now since you have passed displayLinks  as a dependency to the useEffect it gets called again. You are  basically going into an infinite loop.

Comment: right. But i don't understand how the dependency is changing when the input field for the URL hasn't been touched/changed. it does print out the first response properly but then without doing anything it again fires that useeffect and adds the 2nd response to the displayLinks array.. I'm a bit confused as to what I'm supposed to do here.

Comment: so the useeffect runs one time regardless there is a change or not. That kickstarts the endless calls

Comment: so is it a better option to not use useeffect? also is it possible to pass my getMakeRequest to onSubmit and remove useEffect altogether? or would that cause issues?

Comment: Tell me what are you trying to achieve exactly. on click the api should be called? if so then move the api call into the onsubmit method.

Comment: yes got it working, i removed the displaylinks from useeffect dependency and altered my if statement which was checking for the displaylinks array with new links before setting it. thanks for help.